# Calculating interrelate results

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given these data :

In a search system, when search was first performed under condition A, there were `rA` search results. When further narrowed down with condition B, `pB`% of these search results remained. If search first performed under condition B produces `rB` search results, what percentage will remain when these are further narrowed down with condition A?

`rA`, `pB`, `rB` represent the numeric values (for instance : rA = 5000,  pB= 30%, rB = 10000)

This sounds easy, but i don't really know where to start with, have never done this kind of math before.

Any helps is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean $p_B =0.3$ when 30% is intended (your notation is contradictory), the number of results remaining when search A is narrowed to B is $$p_B r_A$$

Similarly, the number of results remaining when search B is narrowed to A is $$p_Ar_B$$

If these are to be equal, we must have that
$$p_B r_A = p_Ar_B$$
so that
$$p_A =\boxed{\left(\dfrac{r_A}{r_B}\right)p_B}
$$

Comment: nice, very easy to understand, thanks alot MPW!